# SSRS Embedded Report on non .NET front end client

Tags: sql, .net, reporting-services

Microsoft's SSRS enables us to embed reports in an `iframe` or `embed` tag. When the page renders, usually you can see the embedded report, minus one caveat. If your SSRS require authentication then you're forced to prompt the USER for credentials. There isn't any method, that I know of, of passing the credentials privately without prompting the user.

My question is how can I embed reports from SSRS using the [URL Access method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15) as I described above without prompting the user for credentials? **I'm not using .NET.**

Comment: If you don't want to prompt user credentials, why not just remove them from the report?

Comment: because we dont want our reports server to be publicly accessible? Just accessible from logged in clients.